# Submit button not working after jQuery interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, buttonclick

I have a form  where I upload files to the server. Everything was working as desired until I added some validation logic to the submit button(disable it while no file is selected and enable it after selection). Now my submit doesn't fire the POST action anymore.
Do I need to explicitly add `onclick` listener? I assume the jQuery modified some properties that prevents the click listener from firing by default?

```html
<form name="uploadFile" method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="importkey" value="Import Key" />
</form>
```

```js
function setSubmitBtnState() {
  var sb = jQuery('#importkey');
  var dclasses = 'ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled';

  if (jQuery('#file').val() == '') {
    sb.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    sb.addClass(dclasses);
  } else {
    sb.removeAttr('disabled');
    sb.removeClass(dclasses);
  }
}
```

Chrome Debugger shows:
Button disabled state

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="importkey" value="Import Key" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled" role="button" aria-disabled="false" disabled="disabled">
```

Button enabled state

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="importkey" value="Import Key" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

So the class is removed.

This code fixed the problem.

```
jQuery("#importkey").button().click(function() {
});
```

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to ensure that the `disabled` attribute and the classes are being removed correctly?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - the button is enabled once I select the file. But it does nothing.

Comment: `ui-state-disabled` adds `pointer-events: none` so ensure the classes are removed too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - classes are removed, plzz see my updates.

Comment: so when is setSubmitButtonState called?

Comment: How is `setSubmitBtnState` called? I would also name your submit button to something other than submit.

Comment: @Snowmonkey - from the 'file'  change handler

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/rjm9vds8/2/

Comment: Ok, I added an empty click listener for the submit button, now it seems to work. I don't know what difference it makes though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make proper validation by calling `setSubmitBtnState()` properly. Try this one:-

```
$('form[name="uploadFile"]').submit(function(e){
   return setSubmitBtnState();
});

function setSubmitBtnState() {
 var isValid = true;
 var sb = jQuery('#importkey');
 var dclasses = 'ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled';

if (jQuery('#file').val() == '') {
   isValid = false;
  sb.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  sb.addClass(dclasses);

} else {
   isValid = true;
  sb.removeAttr('disabled');
  sb.removeClass(dclasses);
 }
 return isValid;
}
```